# Include read-only segments of shared libraries in core dump created by GDB gcore

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, elf, coredump

I used *gdb* to produce core dump file with *gcore* and used the dump in symbolic execution. However I found it did not include read-only segments in memory, for example, the loaded library `libc.so.6`. Unfortunately, I need it for symbolic execution.

Is there a way to make core dump also include those read-only segments?

---

EDIT:

I changed value in /proc//coredump_filter to 0x3c to allow: 
`" Dump file-backed shared mappings"` according to [core(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html). However, `gcore` now gives dozens of warnings:

```
warning: Memory read failed for corefile section, 1048576 bytes at xxxxxx
```

,where xxxxxx is roughly the memory region where shared libraries (including libc, etc.) lies in the memory. However I want the core file to include shared libraries.

What is wrong?

ps: I can read from memory regions of shared libraries inside gdb normally with a plain gdb command `x /16i`.

---

EDIT:

I also checked `/proc/<pid>/smaps`, inside which, for example, memory region of `libc` is like:

```
7f65930f8000-7f65932df000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 789499                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.27.so
Size:               1948 kB
KernelPageSize:        4 kB
MMUPageSize:           4 kB
Rss:                 836 kB
Pss:                  82 kB
Shared_Clean:        836 kB
Shared_Dirty:          0 kB
Private_Clean:         0 kB
Private_Dirty:         0 kB
Referenced:          836 kB
Anonymous:             0 kB
LazyFree:              0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
Shared_Hugetlb:        0 kB
Private_Hugetlb:       0 kB
Swap:                  0 kB
SwapPss:               0 kB
Locked:                0 kB
VmFlags: rd ex mr mw me sd
```

I presume the default value 0x33 in `coredump_filter` should be sufficient to dump this region.
Also as VM flags do not include `dd (do not include area into core dump)`, it was not prevented from being written to core file, but why `gcore` did not dump it???